# How many days Sutak should be followed by an unmarried granddaughter, on the death of grandfather's brother's wife?

Tags: rituals, death

My paternal grandfather's brother's wife passed away and there are lot of contradictory statements we are getting over the Sutak period that is applicable to  me in this case. Should it be three and half days or ten days?

Comment: I don't think any Sutak is applicable in this case as the relation is very far away.

Comment: Sutak is observed based on closeness of relationship.  For Sapinda relatives - same gotra upto seven generations the period is ten days.  For married daughters on the paternal side it is three and half days, else just half a day. Unmarried daughters are still in the same gotra. So some people say the period should be ten days. However, generally for daughters the period is three and a half days.